# How to backup *and restore* a mediawiki server

Tags: server, backup, mediawiki

I have a typical local installation of mediawiki in Ubuntu 10.04. And I am going to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04. How can I quickly backup the wiki content and afterwards restore it back?

All sites I found mention the `sqldump` command to dump the database but I am not sure how I will restore it back.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using mysql (mediawiki works w/ pgsql too I think):

Be warned, mysqldump will lock your tables so they don't change while reading them. If you have converted them to InnoDB (not the default, but highly recommended) then you can add `--single-transaction` below, and they won't be write-locked:

```
mysqldump --user root --password root_pass your_database > file.sql
```

copy file.sql to new server

```
mysqladmin create your_database
mysql --user root --password root_pass -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database.* TO user_name@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'"
mysql --user user_name --password pass < file.sql
```

Don't forget to copy your uploaded files directory as well (use scp or rsync), good luck!